# Excel VBA UDF transiently returns #NAME? after a (different) macro runs

Tags: excel, vba

I have a UDF called GetSimData() defined in a Module called GSD_GetSimData (no name clash there), that I call from cells to retrieve data. The data is stored in VBA Dictionaries, and a persistent 'dump' is stored on a special sheet - and the VBA Dictionaries get loaded whenever VBA memory gets flushed (closing the file, or VBA falls over with an unhandled error etc.). This all works fine for all users (of order 100 users).

I have an XLAM add-in that goes and retrieves the actual data, places it on the special persistent-storage sheet in a given Workbook and flushes the VBA Dictionaries (to trigger a reread of the persistent storage), and also marks all cells using the GetSimData() function as .Dirty; so that they will recalculate at the end of the macro, when automatic calculation gets re-enabled.

The issue I have is that for one user (so far), the GetSimData UDF works fine, except immediately after they run the add-in 'retrieve data' macro, where their Excel seems to return #NAME? for ALL instances of the UDF that was previously working. The remedy is a tedious case of entering any of the UDF cells, then pressing Enter to force recalculation, which then propagates across the whole workbook. Annoying but not show-stopping.

Specific questions:

1. Has anyone got experience of performance limitations causing this behaviour? i.e. are there just too many UDF calls (thousands) in this particular workbook, leading to some sort of timeout?
2. Is there a good article on all possible causes of #NAME? errors, so I can at least try to eliminate the ones it cannot be, and perhaps know where to look for the source of the error here?
3. Has anyone got an similar experience of a 'transient' #NAME? error that reproducibly occurs but is fixed by just forcing the cell(s) to recalculate?

I cannot share the actual code, unfortunately, as I would usually do, because it is highly complex outside the scope of the above simplified overview; and is also commercially sensitive. If there are specific parts of the code that you would like to inspect as a likely source of the issue, I can edit the post to include these.

Comment: does that user have their calculation set to automatic?

Comment: The XLAM forces calculation to Manual during its run, and then back to Automatic at the end of its activities, so the answer is 'yes' at the point the issue occurs.